# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression when i import jquery and boostrap js

Tags: jquery, reactjs

when I try to import my bootstrap and jquery file this error how can I include my javascript library like other scripts in react js

Comment: jQuery + react = bad idea

Comment: Can you please add more context or a working code example?